# I am getting this error - Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript

```
const cardsList = [
                    "fa fa-diamond",
                    "fa fa-paper-plane-o",
                    "fa fa-anchor",
                    "fa fa-bolt",
                    "fa fa-cube",
                    "fa fa-anchor",
                    "fa fa-leaf",
                    "fa fa-bicycle",
                    "fa fa-diamond",
                    "fa fa-bomb",
                    "fa fa-leaf",
                    "fa fa-bomb",
                    "fa fa-bolt",
                    "fa fa-bicycle",
                    "fa fa-paper-plane-o",
                    "fa fa-cube",
                    ];

const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');

function gameStart(){
        let cardShuffle = shuffle(cardsList);
        deck.innerHTML = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < cardShuffle.length; i++){
            deck.appendChild(cardShuffle);
      }
}
```

I am designing a memory game whenever I am calling the function gameStart() on window load, I am getting Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: ___`parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`___

Comment: Your `shuffle` function is not returning a Node that can be appended to the DOM

Comment: `appendChild` expects to be passed a DOM node. It looks like you are passing a string instead. Please [read documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: So, how can I make it work, any suggestions

Comment: Can you all your full code. There is a lot of problems with your code. Query selector return an array of elements. You should loop via ``deck[i]``.

Comment: Create and append a text node. [Learn more about how the DOM works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: As a comment, I do not believe this question deserves a down-vote.  We come to Stack Overflow to ask questions, so we shouldn't be punishing inexperienced programmers for doing just that.

Comment: @gerardo nope, thats `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @brandon [definetly!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)

Comment: @JonasW. it worked thank you so much, I am beginner in DOM manipulation.

Comment: @abishek glad to help :) (the next time you could directly comment under the answer, otherwise it might confuse others...)

Comment: @JonasW. for sure, but after editing my querySelector, I am getting a new error deck.appendChild is not a function

Comment: @abishek wait a minute ... `it worked` was related to the `querySelectorAll` comment? Why should that work? I was just trying to make Gerardo aware of his false statement

Comment: @JonasW. Sorry for my statement, actually my node error is gone

Answer (score 0):

"fa fa-diamond" seems like a class name to me. So if I assume that you want `<div class="fa fa-diamond"></div>`

In the loop, but could be better in a forEach:

```
let node = document.createElement('div');
node.className = cardShuffle[i];
deck.appendChild(node);
```

// will create a `<div class="fa fa-diamond"></div>`, ...

Comment: actually it is li  <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>, I have the starter html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but if i had to guess, I think that you are trying to use font awesome.

Since you didn't provide the shuffle functionality I created a custom one here, which probably doesn't do what you want.

```js
const cardsList = [
"fa fa-diamond",
"fa fa-paper-plane-o",
"fa fa-anchor",
"fa fa-bolt",
"fa fa-cube",
"fa fa-anchor",
"fa fa-leaf",
"fa fa-bicycle",
"fa fa-diamond",
"fa fa-bomb",
"fa fa-leaf",
"fa fa-bomb",
"fa fa-bolt",
"fa fa-bicycle",
"fa fa-paper-plane-o",
"fa fa-cube",
];
const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
function gameStart(){
        let cardShuffle = shuffle(cardsList);
        deck.innerHTML = "";
        for(let i = 0; i < cardShuffle.length; i++){
            var node = document.createElement("i");
            node.className = cardShuffle[i];
            deck.appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="deck"></div>
        <button onclick="gameStart();">Start game</button>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: // Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976   My shuffle function

Comment: I have replaced the shuffle function with the one you provided :)

Comment: Cool :) - we are all looking forward to see your final game

Answer (score -1):

You can use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to add text:

```
deck.textContent += cardShuffle;
```

`appendChild` just takes Nodes, which can be created with `document.createElement`.